# Lumia 925 with 8.1 cannot boot further than Nokia logo

Tags: lumia-925

lumia 925 with 8.1 was working well. overnight observed the phone just cannot boot further than the Nokia highlighted on the screen. Tried the down volume button + power button phone reset but the status remain same nothing changes.

Comment: *Which* key presses did you try to initiate the reset?

Comment: Does it just sit there, or does it get stuck in a reboot loop?

Comment: Check whether you have followed this ; http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/reset-my-phone